# Getting width of View make an exception 'Attempt to read from field on a null object reference'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to getting a width value of TextView by

```
TextView textViewA = new TextView(Context);

textViewA.Text = "Test";
textViewA.Measure(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
int width = textViewA.MeasuredWidth;
textViewA.Text = width.ToString();
```

The error **'Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object reference**' is occurred at `textViewA.Text = width.ToString();`

Addtionally, I encounter this error when I use Measure.
How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Since the null object appears to be width, that means `textViewA.MeasuredWidth` is returning null.

Have you tried using `TextViewA.getMeasuredWidth()`?

Comment: sadly.. I think, in Xamarin TextView has no such method, getMeasuredWidth()

Answer (score 0):

> The error 'Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object reference' is occurred at textViewA.Text = width.ToString();

I made a demo and reproduced the problem. It seems the text can only be changed before `measure`. But in your case you need to get the `MeasuredWidth`. So I found a workaround:

Attach your `textViewA` to your Activity before changing the Text:

```
textViewA.Measure(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
var root = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.root);
root.AddView(textViewA,LayoutParams.MatchParent);// append the textViewA to activity fix the problem
int width = textViewA.MeasuredWidth;
textViewA.Text = width.ToString();
```

And the error will be gone.